# How to programmatically test if assertions are enabled?

Tags: java, scjp, assertion, ocpjp

One of the correct answers from OCP Java SE 6 Programmer Practice Exams is:

> You can programmatically test wheather assertions have been enabled
>   without throwing an `AssertionError`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use this

```
boolean assertOn = false;
// *assigns* true if assertions are on.
assert assertOn = true;
```

I am not sure this is the "official" way.

Comment: Every time `true` is `false` ;)

Comment: And looking at @Joe's answer, apparently the "official" way, too.

Comment: They even call it "straightforward", so please delete your comment again, @PeterLawrey :D

Comment: *I am not sure this is the "official" way*  -- it's not. 2 beers fine for not knowing the core classes in Java (since 1.4) `Class.desiredAssertionStatus()`

Comment: @Thilo, it's not the official way, it's a well defined API function in `Class` to do so.

Answer (score 31):

I guess you should use [`Class.desiredAssertionStatus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#desiredAssertionStatus())

Comment: This avoids the possible "accidental assignment" warning that comes with the other approach.

Comment: Actually, from the javadoc: "Note that this method is not guaranteed to return the actual assertion status that was (or will be) associated with the specified class when it was (or will be) initialized.". So this answer seems incorrect to me, and you should consider Joe's answer.

Comment: @FBB, I'm guessing it should be safe to invoke this method from inside an instance of the class you are testing against (because the class is guaranteed to be initialized).

Comment: @Gili: "when it *was* (or will be) initialized". So, no, the javadoc states it is not safe, even if the class was correctly initialized.

Comment: @FBB the other answer has exactly the same issue, it only checks whether assertions are enabled at the point the assertion is (or isn't) evaluated.

Answer (score 23):

The Oracle Java Tutorial provides information about how to do it...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

An excerpt from the tutorial

> 7. Why not provide a construct to query the assert status of the containing class?
>
> Such a construct would encourage people to inline complex assertion
>   code, which we view as a bad thing. Further, it is straightforward to
>   query the assert status atop the current API, if you feel you must:
>
> ```
> boolean assertsEnabled = false;
> assert assertsEnabled = true; // Intentional side-effect!!!
> // Now assertsEnabled is set to the correct value
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
RuntimeMXBean mx = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
boolean assertionsEnabled = mx.getInputArguments().contains("-ea");
```

Comment: Assertions can be enabled per-class and package, and can be changed by instrumentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using AssertsEnabled from jdk.nashorn.internal.

```
System.out.println(AssertsEnabled.assertsEnabled());
// "assertsEnabled()" returns boolean value
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Official solution*:

[image]

Source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/javadoc-next/api/nashorn/rev/fa79d912da1b#l1.38

---

* As official as it gets:

As mentioned by [@Hurkan Dogan here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62136929/878361) there was a `AssertsEnabled.assertsEnabled()` api in nashorn package which is now deprecated. However, its implementation could be considered as the official solution.

Also note that this solution is also [written in the official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) and mentioned by [@Joe here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030362/878361)

Answer (score -1):

```
package io.github.baijifeilong.tmp;

import io.vavr.control.Try;

/**
 * Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2019-04-18 09:12
 */
public class TmpApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Try.run(() -> {
            assert false;
        }).onSuccess($ -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Assertion is not enabled");
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe help someone.

Comment: OP asked specifically for a solution "without throwing an AssertionError"

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean ea=false;
try { assert(false); }
catch(AssertionError e) { ea=true; }
```

Comment: OP asked specifically for a solution "without throwing an AssertionError"